# Cannot receive messages through AWS IoT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-iot

I imported AWS Cognito user pool.
I tried to receive messages though AWS IoT, but no luck.

Do you need to set Identity pool?

This is my aws-exports.js

```
const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "ap-xxxxxx-1",
    "aws_cognito_region": "ap-xxxxxx-1",
    "aws_user_pools_id": "ap-xxxxxx-xxxxxx",
    "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "xxxxxx",
    "oauth": {
        "domain": "xxxxxx.amazoncognito.com"
    },
    "aws_cognito_username_attributes": [],
    "aws_cognito_social_providers": [],
    "aws_cognito_signup_attributes": [
        "EMAIL"
    ],
    "aws_cognito_mfa_configuration": "OFF",
    "aws_cognito_mfa_types": [],
    "aws_cognito_password_protection_settings": {
        "passwordPolicyMinLength": 8,
        "passwordPolicyCharacters": [
            ....
        ]
    },
    "aws_cognito_verification_mechanisms": [
        "EMAIL"
    ]
};


export default awsmobile;
```